# Token becomes invalid after closing the browser

Tags: php, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am using Symfony for the back end and [this](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) for authenticating the user. When I close the browser, and open the application and make a call to web service, the token is invalid.

How do I make the token remain valid even after closing the browser.

Comment: Could you please also add your configuration for LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle and in your `security.yaml`? Maybe this will help us spot any errors

Comment: i dont get your question. You want the token to stay valid forever? when you close the browser, your session gets removed or reset, so token is invalidated, thats how it s supposed to be

Answer (score -1):

for reason of security, i image the token was linked to your ip, or any kind of information or simply the token expire, so you need to refresh this token, for example, autologin, or similar, if you are using  JWT see [this](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#notes) docs and using JWTRefreshTokenBundle.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is just a guess. You should post only answers that solve the problem.

Comment: in this question specially dont show us any piece of code about how is working also dont provide any explication about the infraestructure, so any response is a guess

Comment: Then you shouldn't write an answer, your answer is just as bad as the question.